# How could I extends class declared as namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript2.7

There is an issue in importing libraries defined in typesciprt 2.7 as below.

In the official typescript document, it provide a "module-class" template. But there is no mention of extending the module class in that document. In this case, when there is a class that inherits, it is often made as follows. However, when I actually reference it, there are compile error that do not find inherited properties.

#### Error

`Property '...' does not exist on type '...'`.

**How can we solve it?**

Note that I'm using the `esModuleInterop` compile option added in 2.7.

---

below is example code of situation.

#### Parent Code & Definition

```
// Code
export default class Parent {
    on() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Definition
declare class Parent {
    on(): this
}

export default Parent;
```

#### Child Library Definition

```
import * as Parent from "parent";

declare class Child extends Parent {
    // ...
    // Parent's "on" method can be noticed here
}

declare namespace Child {
    // ISSUE
}
```

#### Usage

```
import Child from "child";

const child = new Child();

// `Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Child'`.
child.on();
```

Comment: Could you add a more complete example ? With the property definition that is causing the issue ?

Comment: Yes. I have modified the example. Is this enough?

Comment: Not really... you should most a minimal functional example that reproduces your problem.. You can't have both a declaration and a definition for the `Parent` class. Your `parent` import is wrong, it should be `import Parent  from "./parent";` And you should post a line of code that produces the error not the comment `// ISSUE`

Comment: That beeing said, I think the way you expect merging to work is not the way it actually works. I don't think the namespace definition will inherit methods from `Parent` namespaces don't have the concept of inheritance. Even if it did, the namespace is added to the static scope of the class so that is what would be accessible, the `on` method is an instance method and there is not `this` inside the `namespace`